# "ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0x0 (expected 0xbca782be)." while mounting a exfat partition

Tags: mount, exfat

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/Seagate Exp1: Command-line
mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/user/Seagate Exp1" exited with non-zero exit
status 1: stdout: FUSE exfat 1.0.1 stderr: `ERROR: invalid VBR
checksum 0x0 (expected 0xbca782be).
```

I tried:

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/exfat
```

I received this error:

FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0x0 (expected 0xbca782be).

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 16.0 GB, 16013942784 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31277232 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000a743

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    31277055    15387649    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    31277055    15387648   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 15.8 GB, 15754854400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1915 cylinders, total 30771200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: 13.7 GB, 13669236736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1661 cylinders, total 26697728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: 2084 MB, 2084569088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 253 cylinders, total 4071424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787025920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60800 cylinders, total 976754645 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x90a33393

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   976754644  3907010388    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Can you please format your question? I tried to edit it, but could not parse it properly...

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Output of `fdisk -l` please?

Comment: @MadMike I am running linux mint 17.  I know it's not ubuntu necessarily but the core is.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat just did

Comment: Also, thanks for your help!  I'm a noob.  Also, I have ubuntu on a virtual computer if I really need to use Ubuntu.

Comment: @ValerieSerluco The core may or may not be Ubuntu, but it doesn't matter: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5877/why-are-questions-about-specifically-ubuntu-based-distros-off-limits

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your device isn't even FAT, so you don't need to use exfat option. Just let mount determine which filesystem the drive is using:

```
sudo mount -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" /dev/sdb1
```

It should be fine, unless your drive doesn't have a filesystem (in which case you need to format it) or the drive is severally damaged.